# jquery how to get the class of parent element using chlid id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to alert the table(parent) class on click using the child id `<th id="first">`.

`alert($(this).parent('tr').attr('class'));` using this i have got the class of the `<tr>`.

But i want to get the class of the table when i use `alert($(this).parent('table').attr('class'));` it showing alert says undefined can someone help me how can the parent class using the child id

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="sample">
        <th id="first">Firstname</th>
        <th id="last">Lastname</th>
        <th id="user">Username</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>arun </td>
           <td>kumaresh</td>
           <td>arun kumaresh</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
        </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#first").click(function(){
       alert($(this).parent('tr').attr('class'));
  });
});    
</script>
```

Comment: `alert($(this).closest('table').attr('class'));`

Comment: `parent` will select the immediate parent. closest would be the right choice at this context.

Comment: OR `alert($(this).parents('table:first').attr('class'));`

Comment: the whole idea of event capturing and event bubbling is not having to do that manually

Comment: if  thead has class then how can i get the name of the class using the  th id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.closest(TARGET_SELECTOR)`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

As [`.parent(SELECTOR)`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), *Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.* (the `parent()` method traverses to the **immediate parent**)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('table').attr('class'));
  });
  $("#last").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('thead').attr('class'));
  });
  $(".user").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('table').attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class='ANY_CLASS'>
    <tr class="sample">
      <th id="first">Firstname</th>
      <th id="last">Lastname</th>
      <th class="user">Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>arun</td>
      <td>kumaresh</td>
      <td>arun kumaresh</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if  thead has class then how can i get the name of the class using the  <th> id

Comment: if  thead has a class <thead class="new">  then how can i get the class name 'new' with the <th id="last">

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
alert($(this).closest('table').attr('class'));
```

refer closest here
https://api.jquery.com/closest/